# Powershell read csv and rewrite with only x first columns

Tags: powershell, csv

We receive from out smaller sites data by csv, but sometimes quite some unneeded comma sign are added to the right of each line.

If found the way on how to read the header line and find the real number of columns that are specified in the reader

```
$realcols = $file[0].psobject.properties.name.count
```

did the trick. But now I would like to read and rewrite the file for the value in realcols.
I've seen plenty of samples with specified column names and select object but I would like to kee this generic, so the script can be used on multiple files.

Any suggestions ?

Code iss ...

```
$file = Import-csv $fileName
$columnNames = @($file[0].psobject.properties.Name)
$columnCount = $columnNames.Count
$file[0]
$columnCount
```

Example CSV

```
CustomerCode,Customer,ISO Country,SIC,EC or IC,Email SalesPerson,Customer Segment (A/B/C/D/E/Z),New Application,,Previous Application,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
6,C INVEST LLC,UA,32,14,serhii.xx@xx.com,?,C/T&E,L,Tiles,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
23,INTER JSC,UA,32,3,Oleksandr.zz@xx.com,Z,C/T,O,Ziles,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

As you can see one of the column headers has even become blank between New Application and Previous Application

Code I hoped to find (as pseudo code sample) was

```
#$new = $file | Select-Object [0,$columncount]

#$new[0]
```

Comment: Please share the code you use to import the CSV, along with a sample CSV file (header + 1 record should be sufficient) that reproduces the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Import-Csv` to have the data parsed.
Because of the empty header where there **is** data, you will receive a warning:
*One or more headers were not specified. Default names starting with "H" have been used in place of any missing headers.*

If you do not care to see that warning, you can specify `-WarningAction SilentlyContinue` to the end of the Import-Csv line

The empty fields with **no data** on the right will be ignored.

```
$data = Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\blah.csv'
# now write the data back to csv file
$data | Export-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\blah2.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

This will create an new file:

```
"CustomerCode","Customer","ISO Country","SIC","EC or IC","Email SalesPerson","Customer Segment (A/B/C/D/E/Z)","New Application","H1","Previous Application"
"6","C INVEST LLC","UA","32","14","serhii.xx@xx.com","?","C/T&E","L","Tiles"
"23","INTER JSC","UA","32","3","Oleksandr.zz@xx.com","Z","C/T","O","Ziles"
```

Here you can see the missing header was renamed to `"H1"` and all empty columns to the right are removed